# Template function specialisation

Tags: c++, templates

How to make a specialisation for a template function with returning value template?

I tried this:

myfunc.h:

```
#pragma once

template< >
int MyFunc<int>(){
   return 10;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "myfunc.h"

int main()
{
    int a;
    a = MyFunc<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

but i have error: expected initializer before '<' token

Comment: Where is the template definition/declaration? You can't specialize a template you haven't even declared yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the primary template before you declare your specialization.

```
template<typename> int func() { return 42; }

template<> int func<int>() { return 23; }
```

Please be aware of the problems of [function specializations](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

Answer (score 2):

You did not declare or define a primary template of which this is a specialization.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to do but maybe this helps you:

```
template<typename T>
int MyFunc(){
   return 0;
}

template<>
int MyFunc<int>(){
   return 10;
}

template<>
int MyFunc<char>(){
   return 100;
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << MyFunc<int>() << endl << MyFunc<char>() << endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```